# How can I create a WooCommerce site with different versions of the info for different countries?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**The thing is:**

I need to use different information (and prices in some cases), for different countries, in the same shop.

We are testing a product, so I just need the **easiest way** to do this to solve it quickly; even if it's not the best practice. But if you want to mention also the best practice I'll thank you because if the product works I'll need to do it sooner or later.

Here you got an example:

[image]
[image]
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use 2 plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/
and you can also also use some plugin like product price based on country.

Comment: Thanks for those plugins. I'll install them. But still, I need something to have different info in both pages; not only the language. I mean, I need to display differente phone numbers, different addresses, and some other stuff.